# unblocking Ribbon WPF assembly for use in VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, metadata

I'm trying to open the sample Solution for the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF, but I get [this error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7f5f2275-9d33-49ae-9970-0a9902905b06) about being unable to load metadata.  The solution on that site, and the one linked in the error, is [How to: Use an Assembly from the Web in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890038(VS.100).aspx).  However, I don't see any 'Unblock' option when I check the Properties dialog for RibbonControlsLibrary.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF\v3.5.40729.1.  This may be because when I downloaded the Ribbon stuff, it wasn't the library directly, but rather an [installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4) for the library.  How can I get rid of this error so I can actually see the design view of the sample XAML files for the Ribbon WPF?

Here is the full error message:

> Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'RibbonWindowSample'. This assembly may have been downloaded from the web.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.  The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly 'RibbonWindowSample' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, it's not `RibbonControlsLibrary.dll` that's at fault, it's  `RibbonWindowSample`. Have you unbolocked the solution file and files that form the project? If `RibbonWindowSample` came pre-compiled, you may need to re-build the solution to generate compiled assemblies that don't have the "web mark" on them.

Comment: I checked the Properties of the Solution and the RibbonWindowSample.csproj file, but neither had Unblock.  You were right that rebuilding the Solution got rid of the error, though!

Comment: My answer wasn't as clear as it could be.. there's actually two possiblities listed there. Have a look inside the ZIP file, in RibbonWindowSample\bin\Release (or \Debug, whichever is the active configuration). I suspect that there'll be a `RibbonWindowSample.dll`... i.e. the content of the project, pre-compiled. It was that file that had the marker on it and you got rid of it by building and thus re-creating it =) I'll re-phrase my answer shortly so it's clearer for anyone that encounters this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download a zip file? You need to unblock the zip before unzipping it. Once it's unzipped you won't be able to unblock the individual files that were in it.

[image]

Here's what to look for at the bottom of the properties dialog.

Comment: It did come from a ZIP file, though I don't see an Unblock option in the Properties of the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the metadata error before building the Solution--it shows up when I first load the Solution.  I tried building it just now and it built fine, plus the design view shows the XAML window.  I don't know why I see the metadata error when it first loads but it goes away upon building.

Comment: see my answer for what might be one reason why it goes away upon building. =)